# Bash missing all shell commands

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to convert by boyfriend's old computer into a development environment because mine broke and I can't afford a new one, but it seems to be missing damn near every shell command I'm used to. It doesn't have `ls` even!

The `help` command gives me this:

```
bash-4.4$ help
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0)
These shell commands are defined internally.  Type `help' to see this list.
Type `help name' to find out more about the function `name'.
Use `info bash' to find out more about the shell in general.
Use `man -k' or `info' to find out more about commands not in this list.

A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled.

 job_spec [&]                            history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or hist>
 (( expression ))                        if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif C>
 . filename [arguments]                  jobs [-lnprs] [jobspec ...] or jobs >
 :                                       kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigs>
 [ arg... ]                              let arg [arg ...]
 [[ expression ]]                        local [option] name[=value] ...
 alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]          logout [n]
 bg [job_spec ...]                       mapfile [-d delim] [-n count] [-O or>
 bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f file>  popd [-n] [+N | -N]
 break [n]                               printf [-v var] format [arguments]
 builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]       pushd [-n] [+N | -N | dir]
 caller [expr]                           pwd [-LP]
 case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...)>  read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [->
 cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]            readarray [-n count] [-O origin] [-s>
 command [-pVv] command [arg ...]        readonly [-aAf] [name[=value] ...] o>
 compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option] [>  return [n]
 complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] >  select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMM>
 compopt [-o|+o option] [-DE] [name ..>  set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option->
 continue [n]                            shift [n]
 coproc [NAME] command [redirections]    shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
 declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=v>  source filename [arguments]
 dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]                  suspend [-f]
 disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ... | pid >  test [expr]
 echo [-neE] [arg ...]                   time [-p] pipeline
 enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [na>  times
 eval [arg ...]                          trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
 exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [argume>  true
 exit [n]                                type [-afptP] name [name ...]
 export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or ex>  typeset [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] name[=v>
 false                                   ulimit [-SHabcdefiklmnpqrstuvxPT] [l>
 fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] o>  umask [-p] [-S] [mode]
 fg [job_spec]                           unalias [-a] name [name ...]
 for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMAND>  unset [-f] [-v] [-n] [name ...]
 for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMAN>  until COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 function name { COMMANDS ; } or name >  variables - Names and meanings of so>
 getopts optstring name [arg]            wait [-n] [id ...]
 hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name >  while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 help [-dms] [pattern ...]               { COMMANDS ; }
```

And looking for the *.bashrc* and *.profile* at *~*, I can't find it. I don't want to break the whole thing, I've got an optimized bash profile from my old computer, but it's obviously assuming the commands from pretty much every other mac command prompt. Any ideas on how to get everything up to sleep? This puppy is a *Macbook Pro* from mid 2012 but running *High Sierra 10.13*.

Comment: What `/bin/ls`?

Comment: What do you get if you run `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `ls` is never in the output of `help` -- `help` only shows you commands that are built into bash itself; `ls` is provided by your operating system vendor, and located by the shell at runtime via inspecting the `PATH`. Thus, it's likely that the `PATH` is invalid (since with High Sierra, it takes significant work to remove protected operating-system-installed binaries, so it's unlikely that the contents of `/bin` were actually removed).

Comment: BTW, `printf '%s\n' *` is a useful place to start if you don't have a working `ls`.

Comment: `ls` is not a shell command.  If you want to know if a command is a built-in, use `type`, for example `type echo`, `type cat`.  It is not unusual not to have a `.bashrc` on MAC, but ask yourself if you need it or should you use `.bash_profile` (rather than `.profile`)?

Comment: Verify that `ls` isn't actually available by `which ls`, and if that's actually not on your `$PATH` anywhere then there's something quite off.  At that point I would do `echo $PATH` to start the investigation.  As @cdarke said, it seems like you might be confusing bash built-ins (shell comands) with the standard UNIX utilities which are accessed by having them in a dir on your `$PATH`.

Comment: @JawguyChooser, `which` is an external util.  If the `$PATH` is borked, `which` won't run, (at least not without the full pathname, *e.g.* `/usr/bin/which` or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

This pure `bash` code uses no external utils, (and therefore **should** run), and will list the command names available in several standard directories:

```
for f in /tmp/num* ; do echo > $f ; done
for f in /bin/* /usr/bin/* /sbin/* /usr/sbin/* ; do \
    test -x "$f" && { n="${f##*/}" ; echo "$n" >> /tmp/num${#n} ; }
done
for f in /tmp/num{1..10} ; do printf %$((${f##*num}+1))s $(<$f) ; done ; echo
```

The output is a little strange, (try it!).  With pure `bash` there's no external utils like `sort`, `column`, *etc.* to make the output more readable, and since it's a pain to make `bash` simulate those utils, I settled for listing all the 1-letter executables together, then the 2-letter executables, then the 3-letter ones, *etc.*, up to 10 letters long.  There are usually many utils on any system with names that are longer than 10 letters, but the ones listed should be enough to set things right.

Why do this at all?  It lets the user with a broken `$PATH` see that all is not hopeless.  Or in rare cases, if it fails, then it *proves* things are indeed in bad shape.

---

After looking at the resulting command dump, suppose the utils needed to fix things are all there.  Here's a pure `bash` function to get their full pathnames:

```
findcommand() { printf "%s\n" /bin/* /usr/bin/* /sbin/* /usr/sbin/* |
                while read x ; do 
                   for f in $@ ; do 
                      [ "${x##*/}" = "$f" ] && echo $x
                done ; done ; }
```

Usage, suppose we really need `sort`, `column`, `ls` and a text-editor:

```
findcommand sort column ls vi jed mcedit
```

Output on my *Lubuntu* system:

```
/bin/ls
/usr/bin/column
/usr/bin/mcedit
/usr/bin/sort
/usr/bin/vi
```

Note that since `jed` is not installed, there's no pathname for it.